# check if String is correct

Tags: java

I have some specific task. We have String like "(()[]<>)" or something familiar with this.
A question in my interview qustion was how check either String is correct or incorrect.
For example: "()[]<>" - true, "([)" - false, "[(])" - false, "([<>])" - true.
Thank you guys very much!

Comment: Hint: use a stack. Try something and come back if you have a specific problem.

Comment: Try use regular expression classes.

Comment: Have to agree with @JBNizet. A Stack is definitely the most appropriate way to parse expressions. Doing the same thing with regexp is possible, but needs tons of lookaheads and lookbehinds, which is never a nice way.

Comment: I`m not stoping but code is wrong

Comment: I rollbacked your edit, since your question didn't make any sense anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to use a stack to process this.

When you find a new opening parenthesis you would push onto the stack.

When you find a closing parenthesis, peek at the top element on the stack - and see if it matches. I.e. if you've just found a ")", was the last element on the stack a "("?

If it was, then pop that element of the stack. If it wasn't then you've got an "incorrect" String and you can stop processing any further.

Also, once you get to the end of the string, if there's anything left on the stack we know there's an non-terminated parenthesis.